# Simple cron job, event email campaign set up

Tags: php, mysql, email, cron

I am trying to set up a small event email campaign using php and cron jobs. Not sure if I can do it with one file and one cron, or if I need to set up a cron and file for each "email" that I automatically send out ?

Here is the set up. We run an event management site, so people come to our website to register their events to promote.

I am trying to get a simple automatic email campaign set up using cron / php script.

**Here is our schedule:**

- 1 week after event added ( send email or ignore if event has been reached )
- 2 weeks after event added ( send email or ignore if event has been reached )
- 30 days before an event ( send email or ignore if event has been reached )
- 14 days before the event ( send email or ignore if event has been reached )
- 7 days before the event ( send email or ignore if event has been reached )
- 7 days after the event ( send email or ignore if event has been reached )

I can easily set up variables for each of those days above from either their "created date" or "date of event"

I am having a tough time putting it all together. Especially, if the event is added 6 days before... So ignoring certain ones by comparing dates will also be key.

Any help would be great getting things in order!

Variables..
if else.. 
logic .. 
email..

Thanks!

Here is some sample code:

```
$date_of_event  = $row_Recordset1['date']; 
$created_date = $row_Recordset1['timeStamp']; 
$one_week_after = date('Y-m-d',strtotime("+7 days" $created_date));
$two_weeks_after = date('Y-m-d',strtotime("+14 days" $created_date));


if ( $created_date >
```

Comment: You'd be better off with `at`, which lets you schedule one-shot jobs for specific dates/times. cron is for repeating jobs at well defined intervals.

Comment: not sure what you mean by at ?

Comment: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-job-scheduling/index.html#N10181

Comment: Well, either `at`, or just run a a daily cron job to see what the work of that day is if you have multiple events...

Comment: Still need help setting this up ?

Comment: if the event is added 6 days before then the only email you send would be the 7 days after, correct?  Or would you also want to send the email that is normally sent 7 days before right away?

Comment: no, i would like it to just ignore those emails, if time comparison doesn't relate!

Comment: The variables and logic are really driving me nuts!!